# Are there any restrictions on Amazon neptune when using gremlin syntax?

Tags: java, gremlin, graph-databases, amazon-neptune

I am using a graph database for my project, Neptune by AWS. Neptune uses gremlin syntax for graph queries. I was trying to execute a scenario where I have to filter the outgoing edges from a vertex on the basis of property on the edge. Let's call that property 'x'. The value of this property 'x' is of the form 'abc::xyz::ref'. This is to store multiple values on the edge, as Neptune does not allow multi values on edges. I have to do a contains check with three combinations and an exact match :-

- 'abc::'
- '::abc'
- '::abc::'
- Exact match with 'abc'

I was trying to use filter command in the gremlin in my java code. The below code works fine with TinkerGraph in-memory, but when I connect it with Neptune and run the same query it throws some parsing exception.

```
 String valueToCheck = "abc";
 List<String> listOfValuesToCheck = new ArrayList<>();
 listOfValuesToCheck.add("::abc");
 listOfValuesToCheck.add("abc::");
 listOfValuesToCheck.add("::abc::");
 GraphTraversal<Vertex, Map<Object, Object>> gt24 = g.V().outE().has("x").filter(it -> { 
      String value = String.valueOf(it.get().value("x"));
      if(value.equals(valueToCheck)){
      return true;
      }else {
        for(String s: listOfValuesToCheck){
            if(value.contains(s){
            return true;
            }
        }
      }
    }).valueMap().with(WithOptions.tokens);
    
    while (gt24.hasNext()) {
      System.out.println(gt24.next());
    }
```

Does someone know, why this is happening with Neptune? And is there a better way to do it that works with Neptune.
I have seen one more instance where Neptune did not throw an error but also gave back no results but the same work with TinkerGraph.

y - property on Edge
z - property on Vertex

```
GraphTraversal<Vertex, Map<String, Object>> gt13 = g.V(1, 2).project("id", "summary").by(T.id)
        .by(__.outE().has("y", "e").inV().group().by("z"));
```

Answer (score 2):

[Neptune doesn't support lambdas steps.](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/neptune/latest/userguide/access-graph-gremlin-differences.html#w3aac12c20c10c13c47)

you should try to replace your lambda code with other gremlin steps.

```
g.V().outE().has("x").or(
        __.has('prop', 'abc'),
        __.has('prop', TextP.containing('abc::')),
        __.has('prop', TextP.containing('::abc')),
    ).valueMap().with(WithOptions.tokens)
```

example: https://gremlify.com/sjrd9lrwfr

Comment: Here you may also be able to make use of Full-Text search in Neptune to avoid the multiple `.has()` steps.

See: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/neptune/latest/userguide/full-text-search-gremlin.html

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are trying to include in line code in your query.   Amazon Neptune does not support that. However, Gremlin includes text predicates such as TextP.containing which you can use instead. The small number of Neptune differences are documented at https://docs.aws.amazon.com/neptune/latest/userguide/access-graph-gremlin-differences.html